# Where are the default Unity lenses stored?

Tags: unity, application-development, filesystem, lenses

I want to create a home build lens for the 12.04 dash and liked to use one of the default lenses as example. I'm thus for looking where I can find the files of these lenses.

Comment: just the folders with lens locations won't be all you need.  you also need .service files and a couple other things.  you should either use the quickly lens template or follow along with some python lens tutorials you can find on google http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/tutorial-on-writing-ubuntu-lensesplaces-in-python/ expresses some other files to be concerned with

Answer (score 2):

There are three essential files that compose a lens.

- A `.lens` file stored in `/usr/share/unity/lenses`. This details the name, icon, and D-Bus address of a lens for Unity.
- A `.service` file stored in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services`. This points to the location of a lens' query executable; D-Bus will see this executable and act as [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) between it and Unity.
- Finally, the executable of your lens may be placed anywhere in the filesystem (you specify where in the `.service` file), but canonically these are located in `/usr/lib`.

Look at `/usr/share/unity/lenses/video/video.lens`, `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/unity-lens-video.service`, and `/usr/lib/unity-lens-video/unity-lens-video` for a concrete example of how these files work together.